# Is there a way to provide mouse/kbd input from one computer into another computer via USB cable

Tags: usb, keyboard, mouse

Okay, I have read the question and answers on this thread:

[How to send keystrokes from one computer to another by USB?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4706849/how-to-send-keystrokes-from-one-computer-to-another-by-usb)

but it is almost 3 years old and there might be a more commercially or otherwise available solution.

I have two PC's at my desk, each connected to a different network, so synergy or similar software based solutions will not work as the two systems are fed by different ISP's, say one from the cable company and other one is telephone company.

I spend most of my time on one of these machines during the day. Hence my external KBD/MOUSE are connected to that machine with physical cables. I can see the display of other computer, which is mostly occupied by a monitoring program, which generally runs by itself. When certain event's take place, I need to access the keyboard and mouse on that machine and do certain things. In the past, these certain things were 2-3 times a day and I didn't mind reaching out to the laptop keyboard on this machine and doing the work locally. Nowadays this frequency went up to few times per hour and reaching to that cramped keyboard is rapidly becoming a hassle.

All I want is, having a special USB cable (which will overcome the USB host/device dilemma) and a piece of software which when activated by a hot key, will pass-thru the kbd/mouse actions to the second computer.

Is such a solution readily available ?

Comment: You can do this with most any kvm (Keyboard/Video/Mouse) switch.

Comment: I am still looking for an answer to this, to do something similar to the KVM module of the GPD Pocket3, allowing it to be KVM for another system. Such a USB cable would make any old/cheap laptop allow it's keyboard and mouse to control another system.

Answer (score 2):

How about a KVM without the "V".  A KVM simply switches the keyboard, video (not in your case) and mouse.  Many KVMs can be switched with a hotkey such as `<shift><shift>`.

Here is one possible product:  http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16817107417

Comment: This one is something like what I had in mind but north of $30 price tag is a little too rich for my penny-pinching blood. I will investigate to see if I can find a cheaper alternative

Comment: Perhaps check ebay, but I'm not sure how much cheaper than $30 you'll get.

Answer (score 1):

what about a virtual network combined with synergy? Programs like Hamachi can make multiple networks act as one virtual network

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion but co-mingling a dedicated work line with my personal line is not something that I would remotely consider.